# Is there a way to nest navbars in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navbar

I have a navbar inside another navbar using jquerymobile like this:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>           
        <li><a href="#" data-tab-class="tab-messages">Messages</a</li>
        <li><a href="#" data-tab-class="tab-details">Details</a</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content tab-messages">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="task-nav"><a data-tab-class="tab-unread">Unread</a></li>
        <li class="task-nav"><a data-tab-class="tab-archived">Archived</a></li> 
        </ul>
</div>    
</div>

<div class="tab-content tab-details">
    <h1>Info for details tab goes here!</h1>
</div>
```

However, when I click on one of the nested tabs, they seem to conflict with the outer tabs and change those too. Is there a way I could maybe use some javascript or jquery to control which ones are selected?

Comment: What do you nean by conflict?

Comment: @Omar every time I click on the inner set of navbar's (the unread tab or archived tab in my example) it changes the main header tabs (the Messages tab or Details tab).

Comment: Can you provide images of this problem? Are you using any JS on the clicked buttons?

Comment: can you post the jquery code? or create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?